# Is it OK to use "empty-handed" on an animal?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

Can I write the following?

> One of the seagulls spotted a fish and dove after it, but came up **empty-handed**

If not, what other word I can use to replace **empty-handed**?

Comment: I've never thought of that before. I suspect "empty-beaked" does not exist but it's a good question nevertheless! :)

Comment: I have no problem with "empty-handed", but I'm quite puzzled at "dropped itself into the water". Dropped? How would one go about dropping oneself?

Comment: @Marthaª I think you're right. What other phrase could I use instead? *Darted into the water?*

Comment: Your edit ("dove after it") is actually perfect, I think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is most definitely acceptable to use the phrase **empty-handed** to describe animals.

Even if the animal you're referring to has no hands, the phrase **empty-handed** is understood to mean "having acquired nothing."

Comment: To add to @EvanTeitelman's answer: English is piled high with metaphor (this very sentence is an example!). Using "empty-handed" is a metaphor, and readers will instinctively know that it is not meant literally.

Answer (score 6):

You can write simply *came up empty* to indicate that its attempt was unsuccessful.  (see [m-w.com's definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20up), below item 6.)

As pointed out in comments, "dropped itself into the water" sounds a bit off.  I would suggest something more like this:

> One of the seagulls spotted a fish and dove after it, but came up empty.

Comment: Or, in British English, "**dived** after it". *dove* as the past tense of *dive* is [N.American](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=dove&title=21st). In Br.Eng. "dove" is a noun referring to a type of bird.

Comment: @trevord, it did occur to me that perhaps I should mention that option.  (note, though, that "dove" the bird is pronounced "duv" (like "love" or "shove"), while "dove" the past-tense action is pronounced with a long o (like "rove" or "clove").

Comment: I agree with you on the pronunciation - and I think I read it that way automatically - but I can't say how a Brit who hasn't come across *dive* meaning *dived* before would pronounce it when first seeing it. :-)

Comment: @TrevorD I think many people would say "dove in", which makes it much easier to parse.

Comment: @Lucas Not if they're British. The 2 dictionaries I referred to do not even recognise *dove* as a British form for the past tense of "dive". (Incidentally, the website link from your Profile gives an error message.)

Comment: @TrevorD I'm a little surprised at that. It's one of those words like "hung" that get used all the time, even if they are wrong in some sense. (thanks for letting me know: gravatar auto-fill)

Answer (score 5):

Gulls have webbed feet with small talons. Empty-taloned or empty-clawed appears to be a reasonable description.

Comment: But do seagulls catch fish with their beaks or with their feet?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Saying the seagull was "empty-beaked" would probably work.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Have you never seen seagulls with fish fingers?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This isn't the right time nor plaice to make such puns.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Surely you mean *thyme nor plaice*?

Comment: @TrevorD  You can't batter me! Not a sole in the world can.

Answer (score 0):

I would write "the seagull `missed its mark.`"

Answer (score -2):

I don't see why you shouldn't use **empty-pawed** instead. It's about as accurate as empty-handed, but cuter.

Comment: Seagulls don't have paws. They have... they have... claws, webbed feet?

Comment: Empty-clawed? >.> Empty-beaked? There's just so many ways to have fun with this.

Comment: "fish-less", "prey-less"?

Comment: Definitely not.  *Empty-handed* is largely metaphorical (if I fail to get a bank loan, I could emerge empty-handed without implying that I expected literal fistfuls of cash), but *empty-pawed* is neither idiomatic nor anatomically accurate.

Comment: Ha, maybe I should use *empty-beaked* just to make the reader laugh.

Comment: I sort of like *empty-beaked*. It has a nice feel to it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'd go with talons for that part of the anatomy, except they don't picks stuff up with them

Comment: Empty-beaked: reader laughs with you.  Empty-handed: reader laughs at you.

Comment: You could also use emotion: "… but it came up frustrated." Personally, I prefer "empty-handed".

Comment: @PaddyLandau Do we know that birds can experience the emotion of frustration?

Comment: @TrevorD Ayup!!

Comment: @TrevorD ­— In this case, the word "frustrated" would refer to a state of being, not necessarily an emotion (e.g. "The bird was frustrated in its attempt to catch the fish"). But even if this were not the case, the word would be a metaphor. People instinctively anthropomorphize animals, toys, and even inanimate objects such as rocks, trees and the sun, starting from early childhood (note how many stories, cartoons, animated movies and other movies are written with animals, toys or other objects as the characters).